# How to achieve this simple flexible page layout using Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, layout, orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard and struggling to determine how to best set up the basic page layout below (simplified for clarity from the actual layout which is based on the [Contoso theme](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Contoso)):

[image]

The piece I'm struggling with is the Right Content area - shown as the dotted red box above. The contents of this area will vary with individual pages. Sometimes it will be empty in which case the solid red Content should expand to fill the content zone. With content it will typically contain 1 or 2 lists of links - specific to the page.

I tried adding a HTML Text Field to the Page content type but then how do I position it? In the Content template (e.g. from the contoso theme ~/Themes/Contoso/Views/Content.cshtml) we can position Model.Content but not individual fields.

Or, if I add another zone on the right hand side of the layout is there a way to place page fields in other zones outside the Content Zone? I tried this in Placement.info as a test:

`<Place Fields_Common_Text="ContentAside"/>`

but it didn't appear in the Content Aside Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<Place Fields_Common_Text="/ContentAside:1"/>` instead.